# Does anyone know if it is possible to return nothing in console for elisp after a function ends?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, return-value

Right now whenever I try to not return anything, I get nil or t.  The last spot of my function ends in an if statement that has nothing in the body. So like this:

```
(if (counter<ten)
    ()
    (...))
```

Comment: The code is (if(counter < ten) () (...)), it didn't print for some reason, Thanks!

Comment: You have both `elisp` and `common-lisp` tags in your question. Which one is it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why getting nil returned is a problem? Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by in the console. I'm assuming you are running an interactive REPL? If this is the case, you may not need to be concerned as once your code is running for 'real' it is unlikely to be in the repl and you won't see the return values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "nothing in the body" is not nothing - it is an empty list `()`, which is the same as `NIL`.

In Common Lisp, you can use the form `values` to return any number of values - including zero:

```
* (defun funny (counter ten)
     (if (< counter ten)
         (values)
         (values 'foo 42)))
FUNNY
* (funny 10 10)
FOO
42
* (funny 9 10)
; No value
```

In Emacs Lisp you always return exactly one value.